# Angular ngSwitchCase - Switch with same value

Tags: angular, switch-statement

I have a ngSwitch where I have different filters which can be of the same type. Now the problem is that when I switch between different filters, with the same type my ngswitch doesn't switch. It only does a switch when the filter.type is a different type (which makes sense but i thought that the switch checks every new filter that is given and creates the component).

Is there a way to switch when the switchcase is the same as before? So that the filter, given to the component is updated?

The filters also have other attributes like "name". I thought about checking if the filter.name changes but that seems to not work too.

```
<div (ngModel)="filter" [ngSwitch]="filter.type">
    <app-filter-one *ngSwitchCase="'1'"  [filter]="filter" ></app-filter-one>
    <app-filter-two *ngSwitchCase="'2'"   [filter]="filter" ></app-filter-two>
    <app-filter-three *ngSwitchCase="'3'"   [filter]="filter" ></app-filter-three>
</div>
```

I hope that makes sense and someone can help,
thanks.

Comment: I think you are trying to say that when filter is changed from for example from `{type: 1, ...otherMetadata1}` to `{type: 1, ...otherMetadata2}` your component isn't updated properly. is it so?

Comment: Yes exactly. I need to update even when the type is the same.

Comment: try to open `app-filter-one` component code and rename `ngOnInit` hook to `ngOnChanges`. this will make your code execute every time the filter is updated, not only on component initialization